# How can I tell gradle to execute uploadArchives on a SNAPSHOT release?

Tags: maven, upload, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, snapshot

I have the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      configuration = configurations.deployerJars
      String keyFile = "/Users/myusername/.ssh/maven@myhost"

      repository(url: "scp://myhost.com/var/maven/repository") {
        authentication(userName: "maven", privateKey: keyFile)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works great - with one caveat: It only uploads release builds. I know that I can specify `snapshotRepository` to get it to upload snapshots, but what I really want is to know how to invoke this behavior. I would like my snapshots to go to the same repo as the release builds (which I think is the default behavior), but when I do:

`./gradlew uploadArchives` or `./gradlew assembleDebug uploadArchives`

it first builds the `release` buildType, and uploads this. How can I tell `uploadArchives` I want it to upload the snapshot build (i.e. debug)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some googling to find a solution so leaving this here for others:

You can make a new task dependent on the `uploadArchives` task but check the version and remove the `dependsOn` and `disable` the task if not a snapshot eg:

```
task uploadSnapshotArchives(dependsOn: uploadArchives) {
    if (!version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
        enabled = false;
        dependsOn = [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to put you versionName with -SNAPSHOT

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {

        snapshotRepository(url: '.../snapshots') {
            authentication(userName: NULL_NEXUS_USER, password: NULL_NEXUS_PWD)
        }

        repository(url: '.../releases') {
            authentication(userName: NULL_NEXUS_USER, password: NULL_NEXUS_PWD)
        }
```

and then `./gradlew clean build uploadFiles` will upload it to snaphots repository.